# How to generate a string based on a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to generate a string based on a regular expression. I have a regular expression and a set of values for subpatterns as below.

Expression: `your-report-([a-z]+)-not-available`
Set: `array("monthly")`

I need to replace the subpattern with value monthly. How do I do it?

Comment: This is not what regular expressions should be used for, they are used for defining a search pattern. You're not searching.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have an URL matchmaking logic implemented using regex. I'm trying to reverse/generate URLs from those regex patterns.

Comment: You question is Unclear.  Please update your question to reveal exact input values and your exact output.  Does your actual array have multiple values in it?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kiko Software. You could use preg_replace with a regular expression but probably it's overly complicating it. Try this instead:

```
$parts = explode('-','your-report-([a-z]+)-not-available')
$parts[2] = "monthly"
$final = implode('-', $parts);
```

It's much easier to read and maintain IMO

Comment: My patterns don't really come with '-' sequence.

Comment: @MunavirChavody how will you extract the part that you want to replace? What makes the part you want to replace it different than the other parts of the string? perhaps some real/better examples of the strings that contain the piece you want to replace would help.

Comment: I have an URL matchmaking logic implemented using regex. I'm trying to reverse/generate URLs from those regex patterns. Say I have a pattern, `^user/(?P<id>)/profile$`. I'm trying to use this pattern to generate url, `user/12/profile` by passing `array("id"=>12)`.

Comment: ah. got it. I think I know what you want

Comment: Can you tell what you know, please?/

Comment: its too hard for me :-P

Comment: I found a solution myself with some regex limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should generate URLs using this way. There is no need to use regular expressions for that task.

```
function generateUrl(string $route, array $parameters = [])
{
    return str_replace(array_keys($parameters), array_values($parameters), $route);
}

echo generateUrl('/your-report-{type}-not-available', [
    '{type}' => 'monthly',
]);

echo PHP_EOL;

echo generateUrl('/client/{clientId}/invoices/{invoiceId}', [
    '{clientId}' => 28,
    '{invoiceId}' => 768,
]);
```

The example above returns:

```
/your-report-monthly-not-available
/client/28/invoices/768
```

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to generate urls. But I already have a version of url matching set up with regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use `preg_replace`, you can try this:

```
preg_replace('(\w*-\w*-)\w*', '${1}monthly', $string)
```